# Can I put storyboard files into different physical folders?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, storyboard

I was moving project files around and noticed that by some reason XCode can't locate my storyboard files. I'm also unable to set their paths with File Inspector - files are not highlighted. Am I allowed to move storyboard files to physical folders?

[image: Part of the project]

Comment: Yes..In your case your logical folder has lost reference from Physical folder for those files. So, remove the file and add again to the logical folder.

Comment: @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃 Wow! It works! Thank you a lot:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**

In your case your logical folder has lost reference from Physical folder for those files. So, remove the file and add again to the logical folder.